# How can I sort a list by month in App Maker?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I want to sort a list in App Maker by month, and I don't know how to it.

[image]

I think that was the way, but is not.

```
@datasource.item.MONTH#sort()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how many ways there are to achieve this but here are two ways:

First one: Go the the **model datasource** and change the **sorting** option to reflect the month and then choose by ascending or descending. See the example below.
[image]

Second one: Select the **table widget** and the go to the **events** section in the **Property Editor**. Click on the **onDataLoad** event and type the following code:

```
widget.datasource.items.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    if (a.Month > b.Month) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
);
```

See the image below:
[image]

Whichever way you prefer, is your choice. Hope it helps!

**Note:** the second option will sort only records withing single page currently loaded to the client.